# Save ArrayList<Object> in Android

Tags: java, android, file, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I am developing an app which will send email in several stages, but I have to check the internet connection. If the user has an internet connection , then I just send the email, but if the user does not have internet then I have to save the email request and send the email when the user regains internet connectivity.

I built an ArrayList and added email requests to that list when the user does not have a connection. How can i save the ArrayList in App permanently? I have to store the list permanently because I need the list even after the user closes and reopens the App.

Comment: You can find the official guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 2):

Simplest answer you need an SQL database of some sort to save the data, although without your code listed you will not get a specific answer.

Learn to use SQL Lite within the application before moving onto connecting to a DB through an internet connection.

This helped me during university: Head over to http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/mini-notepad/.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your list to a json String, you can use gson, jackson or any other json converter.

add the following class to your project:

```
public class JSONCache {
    private static Context context = null;

    public static void init(Context context) {
        if (JSONCache.context == null) {
            JSONCache.context = context;
        }
    }
    public static String loadData(String prefName, String key) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getString(key, null);
    }
    public static void saveData(String prefName, String key, String json ) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
        ed.putString(key, json);
        ed.commit();
    }
    public static void deleteAllData(String prefName) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
        ed.clear();
        ed.commit();
    }
    public static void deleteDataByKey(String prefName, String key) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs.edit();
        ed.remove(key);
        ed.commit();
    }
    public static boolean dataExists(String prefName, String key) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return prefs.getAll().containsKey(key);
    }
}
```

init your cache by calling JSONCache.init and passing the context (this is normally the activity you are on)

Now whenever you need to save just call:

```
 JSONCache.saveData("myPreference", keyForSave, jsonStringToSave);
```

To Fetch from cache

```
String json=JSONCache.loadData(myPreference, jsonStringToSave)
```

you can then use the same json converter from before to turn your json string back into a list.

Answer (score -1):

I guess database would be an overkill, you can simply write the mail addresses to a file or save them in the `SharedPreferences` you can read about different storages here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: There are code samples in the given link.

Comment: it is only adding int , String, Boolean etc, but not any object list

Comment: You can iterate over a list and get strings, bools etc.

Comment: my list is not String or bool, my list is a List of a Class object